# PHP Lucene - Indexation - Fails in Linux after 2.000.000 system blocks

Tags: php, linux, lucene

I have been working on creating an index using Zend Framework latest version. The interface is working fine and everything else.
The problem I have now is the "re-indexation" or creation of the index. I have checked everything else, sanitizing the data and double checking the quality of the data.

The Process always stops at most likely record 15.000 and the limit on the index dir of 2.000.000. That I decided to build an application compiled in java with version lucene3.0.3 to run the indexation.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Search_Lucene_Exception' with message 'Unsupported segments file format' in
```

It seems the latest format used by Zend Lucene is 2.3

Any ideas how to solve this problem, I really appreciate your input

Comment: Not sure what you mean by system blocks (or 'index dir'). But I'm guessing you mean some OS limitation, so run the command `ulimit -a`. If any of the results do NOT say 'unlimited', then post the output as an edit to your question. Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with this. But on the zend lucene website they state that the currently supported lucene index version is 2.3. It might be the case that version 3.0.3 is not fully supported.

> [1] The currently supported Lucene index file format version is 2.3 (starting from Zend Framework 1.6).

See: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.java-lucene.html

Comment: //This is my main  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {    
    String indexDir = args[0]; //1
    
    System.out.println("indexDir " + indexDir );

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Indexer indexer = new Indexer(indexDir);
    int numIndexed = 0;
    String par = "%";
    
    try {
     numIndexed = indexer.index_main( par );
    } finally {
      indexer.close();
    }
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println("Indexing " + numIndexed + " files took "
      + (end - start) + " milliseconds");
}
private IndexWriter writer;

Comment: public Indexer(String indexDir) throws IOException {
    Directory dir = FSDirectory.open(new File(indexDir));
    writer = new IndexWriter(dir,            
                 new StandardAnalyzer(       
                     Version.LUCENE_23),  
                 true,                      
                 IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.LIMITED); 
  } //What is the set up for my FileWrite instance to be compatible with 2.3?

Comment: Is there that have experience problems with reindexing in PHP...? I do not think I am going to use the reindex from PHP directly..anyone can help me with Java then?

Comment: @CarlosRamirez : Please move the code in the comments into the body of the question and use the formatting provided. If we're going to help you, you have to help us. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I customized the example of this site http://www.techcrony.info/?p=33, this example reads text files from a data dir. So, the new customized functions need to read the info from the MySQL database:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{....System.out.print("Index dir arg_0 : " + indexDir + "\r");
    String id ="%";

    long start = new Date().getTime();
    int numIndexed = index_main(indexDir, id);
    long end = new Date().getTime();

    System.out.print("End Program... \r");

}  
private static int index_main(File indexDir, String id )throws IOException {

    int numIndexed = 0;
    try{
        IndexWriter writer =
            new IndexWriter(indexDir, new StandardAnalyzer(), true);
        writer.setUseCompoundFile(false);

      java.sql.Connection conn = linktodata();
      int rowCount = 0;
     ...
```

As you can see I used the lucene-core-2.3.0.jar

```
javac -cp .:lucene-core-2.3.0.jar:mysql-connector-java-5.1.16-bin.jar Indexer.java

Run:

java -cp .:lucene-core-2.3.0.jar:mysql-connector-java-5.1.16-bin.jar Indexer /home/public_html/index_main
```

Now the most important question, is anyone aware if PHP lucene is able to manage more than 1.000.000 documents?

Comment: "is anyone aware if PHP lucene is able to manage more than 1.000.000 documents?".  I used Zend_Lucene about 3 years ago, with a index that was a few hundred meg, maybe a gig.  We switched to solr and never looked back.  There were many queries for which Zend_Lucene took literally 1000x longer than solr (queries that take ms on solr, took seconds in Zend_Lucene).  IMO, don't use Zend_Lucene for anything more than a few thousand small documents, tops.  It's a handy way to offer search over a very small document set in a pure-PHP app, but that's about it.