# Can PHP Zend Lucene handle indexes of over 1 million documents?

Tags: php, zend-framework, lucene

Is anyone aware of have the experience of using PHP Zend Lucene ( search engine ) with repositories of more than 1 million.

Thanks for your feedback

[Indexing with PHP Lucene with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6295570/php-lucene-indexation-fails-in-linux-after-2-000-000-system-blocks)

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want good performance, you may want to consider using sphinx over PHP Zend Lucene, unless your project requires Lucene indexes.

When I was looking at this a year or so ago, I found some benchmarks comparing PHP Lucence vs sphinx. Sphinx won by a long shot.

Answer (score 0):

A lot depends on the architecture of your application, but I wouldn't worry about the number of items. Lucene is known of being slow (building indexes) on *very* large projects, but has a nice upgrade to [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/).

> Solr is the popular, blazing fast open
>   source enterprise search platform from
>   the Apache Lucene project. Its major
>   features include powerful full-text
>   search, hit highlighting, faceted
>   search, dynamic clustering, database
>   integration, rich document (e.g.,
>   Word, PDF) handling, and geospatial
>   search. Solr is highly scalable,
>   providing distributed search and index
>   replication, and it powers the search
>   and navigation features of many of the
>   world's largest internet sites.

Answer (score 0):

I have no direct experience, but I have seen complaints that Zend Lucene is both slow and memory intensive, so much so that it actually fails with "large" indices and "small" memory constraints. Of course, what constitutes a large index and a small memory constraint is essence of the issue.

The following two threads contain some specifics that seem to suggest that 1 million documents is likely to be trouble:

- [Fatal Error Search Lucene Memory Size](http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=69&t=4239)
- [Recommendation: Don’t use Zend PHP Lucene!](http://dadabase.de/weblog/archives/2009/07/22/recommendation-dont-use-zend-php-lucene)

Other developers whom I respect speak very well of [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/) for both speed and memory.

Personally, I am considering trying out Zend Lucene on a small project - probably no more than 1,000 documents in the index because I am restricted to shared hosting (as far as I understand, Sphinx requires an external daemon). But I'm still crossing my fingers.